Getting protocol error when trying to querying in Sybase
I am getting the below error while query a simple table having 20k records, when I run with limit of 100 it works, but when I increased the limit, it throws the below error.
ct_fetch(): protocol specific layer: external error: There is a tds protocol error. An illegal token was received

Sybase version: Adaptive Server Enterprise 12.5.0.1
Can someone please suggest on it?

Please update the question with more details; what is your front-end/application (isql? GUI? compiled program?)? what do you mean by limit of 100 ... are you using 'set rowcount 100', using the limit/offset clause in a select, a GUI config/preference setting? assuming you're not currently using (command line) isql, what happens if you run your query via isql (objective being to rule out an issue with your front-end/application)?
